How do I get Playwright to find a hidden div with wait for selector
I have a div in the page
<div aria-hidden="true" style="display:none" data-testid="thiscontext"/>

I am doing the following to find it
await page.waitForSelector('div[data-testid="thiscontext"]', { hidden: true, visible: false, timeout: 5000 })

I keep getting errors
- waiting for locator('div[data-testid="thiscontext"]') to be visible
-   locator resolved to hidden <div aria-hidden="true" style="display:none" data-testid="thiscontext"></div>

How do I wait for selector on an element that will not ever have a visible display.
I know the hidden and visible options are supposed to be mutually exclusive, but I have also tried with hidden set to true without setting visible, and with visible set to false without setting hidden, and neither one works.
If I change the div in my page to be
<div aria-hidden="true" data-testid="thiscontext">Hi</div>

then the waitForSelector works.

please don´t use waitForSelector. Better approach is page.getByTestId(/thiscontext/), in your case. -> reference . What you can do await expect(<your_hidden_locator>).not.toBeVisible() -> reference or omit .not depending what you need.

Klim's suggestion is good. <div> isn't a self-closing tag so I don't understand the first HTML snippet. Is this your page, or what are you trying to achieve exactly?

the div is my html output by react, I found it in the browser's rendering of the html in the developer panel so it is present in the dom. And I believe the errors show it as being caught
